# read and write to file from user input and stop upon hitting Alt+X

Tags: java

I try to make a program that reads user input and write it into a file.  If a file has already contains some character, it will append new character rather than overriding them.  As the user inputs Alt+X the program stop receive inputs and save the file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//import java.lang.System.*;

public class cTedit implements ICommand{

    @Override
    public void Execute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.out.println("Enter the file name");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the file name");
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = scan1.nextLine();
    //FileWriter fWriter = null;
    //FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(text);
    //BufferedWriter writer = null;
    //BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);

    try{
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        fWriter = new FileWriter(cShell.Currentpath+"\\"+filename);

        writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        //writer.append(text);
        writer.write(text);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
        System.err.println("Text saved");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
       }
   }
```

The thing is the program always override the content of the file plus it only takes one line (i.e. if pressing enter, program stops which is not what it's supposed to do...)

Any help..

Comment: writer.write(text); overwrites over the exsting content.. You have to rad the whole file, then write it back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use `writer.append(text);` instead of `writer.write(text);`

Comment: are you sure that implementation / behaviour of append() is different from that of create() in this case i.e, will changing "write" to "append" work ?